# Can I specify which adapter is used when creating a legacy Wifi Direct Soft Access Point in Windows 10 UWP .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, wifi, wifi-direct

I am attempting to use Wifi Direct to create a hotspot for my local computer to connect with my VR headset. I want to connect one AP to the internet to handle all the internet traffic, and my other AP as a dedicated connection.

I want to write some software to set up this unusual configuration. I downloaded the [Wi-Fi Direct sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/wifidirect/) from MSDN, and read through the code. There doesn't seem to be any code specifically selecting an adapter from which the Wi-Fi direct connection is initiated.

How might I force a direct wifi connection to use a specific adapter, using C# code?

Comment: We are consulting other engineers for your question. There may be some delay.

Answer (score 1):

WiFi Direct will only be able to use the first adapter that is enumerated by the system. You could not use C# code to specify an adapter for a WiFi connection. The only way to alter the behavior is to disable the other WiFi devices in device manager to ensure that the one you want to use is selected.